# Store a somewhat large set of key-value pairs in my laptop?

Tags: database, key-value-store

I have about 44 million key-value pairs on my hand that need to be stored in my laptop.  The keys and values are all short texts, and the keys are all unique.  The total size of them is about several gigabytes.

I tried to store them in a GDBM database.  The problem is whenever I insert a new record, GDBM would check the existence of the key, and it gets slower and slower as the database grows.  My storing program ran for 2 hours without signs of finishing soon, so I gave up.

So now I’m looking for a key-value database system that

- Is reasonably quick when adding records, preferably independent with database size.
- Is preferably simple and small, so that I don’t have to run a load of daemons (best if no daemon at all) on my laptop.  I don’t need to access this database often.
- Is easy and quick to access.  At least I shouldn’t need to load the whole database in memory.  I’ve thought about just storing them in a big XML/JSON file, but it will be a pain to load it and access entries (…right?).
- Ideally stores everything in a single file.
- Ideally has Python interface.  Although I don’t mind writing C/C++.

I don’t need to access the database often (maybe weekly, or monthly, that kind of frequency).  It’s just for my personal use, so no master-slave/concurrency/load-balancing magic is needed to be involved.  I may need to look up some entries from time to time, or sometimes iterate over the whole set once or twice for some statistics.  I will not usually (maybe never) change the data once it’s initially stored.

I’m using a 2011 Macbook Pro (no SSD) with OS X, if it helps.

What database should I use?

---

UPDATE: I’ve been testing some of the key-value DBs, including Google’s leveldb.

…

…

…

Then I updated my public beta version of OS X 10.10 (which I was using for all these) to the release version, the problem disappeared… … … DBMs are all fast now actually.

Comment: try out redis, http://redis.io. However you didn't tell us very deeply how you access your data, if manually or scripts or software or whatever, so other solutions may be better. Also, you could start your redis deamon just only when you need to access your data, no reason to have it running always (are you using windows?).

Comment: Hey @faboolous, thanks for your comment.  I’m adding more information to my question.  I know of Redis.  I just think it’s kinda overkill for such a simple problem.  But maybe at the end I’ll have to use it.  Does it support storing data in a single file?

Comment: redis excels at being a key-value store - that's actually what you're looking for...but indeed it might be overkill for your needs. There seems to be an append-only-file option but I am not sure that's what you need

Comment: @faboolous, it seems the append-only-file thing is a stretegy against data loss from sudden termination… So probably not useful for me…

Comment: Chronicle Map would do what you want, it can do up to 10 million updates/inserts/deletes per second on a Macbook (with an SSD), there is no daemons, it loads only what you need into memory, uses one file, but it's for the JVM only. Would you consider Jython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try koyoto cabinet.
http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/

Comment: Thanks I’ll try it.  The fact that it is an implementation of DBM is encouraging XD